# Django form "takes exactly 1 argument (2 given) " error - possibly related to CSRF?

Tags: django, forms, post, csrf

I am attempting a fairly simple form on Django 1.3, and am trying to understand how CSRF works.

I think I've followed the [three steps detailed on the Django site](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/), but am still unable to make the form work.

The form displays when the URL is loaded, however upon hitting the submit button, I get the following error:

> TypeError at /txt/ txt() takes exactly
>   1 argument (2 given)

Here's the actual code:

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext

def txt(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        msg="txt received"
    else:
        msg="nothing in POST"
    return render_to_response('base.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The HTML:

```
<body>

    <form action="txt/" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        From <input type="text" name="From"><br>
        To <input type="text" name="To"><br>
        Body <input type="text" name="Body"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

    {{ msg }}

</body>
```

I know I haven't done a forms.py etc. but I was just trying to get the basic functionality up and going. I think this code would have worked in previous versions of Django, and am unsure why its not working this time.

Comment: can you add also the urls ? nothing is wrong so far ...

Comment: Yes, urls.py had the problem - needed to replace (r'^txt/(.*)$', txt) with (r'^txt/$', txt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error looks like your view function is getting more arguments than it is setup to accept.  As you have it shown above, the view only accepts a single argument: the request.

If your URL pattern for this view is configured with a capturing group, or you are adding extra arguments via the [optional dictionary](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) or the [kwargs parameter to url()](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#django.conf.urls.defaults.url), then those extra arguments will be given to the view function and could cause the error you're seeing.

Comment: Ah... rookie mistake in urls.py, as you anticipated. 
Needed to replace (r'^txt/(.*)$', txt) with (r'^txt/$', txt)
Thanks!